# How to use python alias module name import child module?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

For example:

I want the below-given syntax to change to two lines.

```
from A.B import C
```

->

```
from A import B
from B import C # I want **B is a child module of A** in this line
```

Why do I need this change?

Because I got an open-source project based on Keras, not tensorflow.keras, and I need to change all keras to tensorflow.keras by doing the change to save time, **instead of adding `tensorflow.` in front of `keras` in all files.**

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
```

->

```
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import optimizers # **keras is child moudle of tensorflow** in this line
```

Is the change possible ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add multiple modules and rename them using:

```
from A.B import C, D as E, F
from G.H import C, D as I, J
```

in your specific case, it gives:

```
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers as optimizers1
from keras import optimizers as optimizers2
```

Then you can use them in python code like this:

```
optimizers1.func1()
optimizers2.func2()
```